# Array out of bounce in Jgrasp

Tags: java, arrays, output

Write several array manipulation methods. One method will sum up a section of a
provided array, another method will count up how many of a certain number occur in the array, and the last
method will remove all of a certain value from the array.

I have done the code but I get out  of bounce: 9 error and I cannot solve it.

```php
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.Math;

public class ArrayFunHouse {
    // instance variables and constructors could be used, but are not really
    // needed

    // getSum() will return the sum of the numbers from start to stop, not
    // including stop
    public static int getSum(int[] numArray, int start, int stop)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int[] locArray = numArray;

        for(int i = start; i<=stop; i++)
        {
            sum+=locArray[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // getCount() will return number of times val is present
    public static int getCount(int[] numArray, int val) 
    {
        int times = 0;
        for (int i : numArray) 
        {
            if (i == val)
                times++;
        }
        return times;
    }

    public static int[] removeVal(int[] numArray, int val) 
    {
        int[] array = new int[numArray.length - getCount(numArray, val)];
        byte index = 0;
        for (int i : numArray) 
        {
            if (i != val) {
                array[index] = i;
                index++;enter code here
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

My runner class

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayFunHouseRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int[] one = {7, 4, 10, 0, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 7};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
        System.out.println("sum of spots 3-6  =  " + 
        ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,3,6));
        System.out.println("sum of spots 2-9  =  " + 
        ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,2,9));
        System.out.println("# of 4s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,4));
        System.out.println("# of 9s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,9));
        System.out.println("# of 7s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,7)); 
        one = ArrayFunHouse.removeVal(one, 7);
        System.out.println("new array with all 7s removed  =  " + 
        Arrays.toString(one));
        System.out.println("# of 7s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one, 7));

       System.out.println();

       int[] two = {7, 4, 2, 7, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 0, 10, 7, 0, 1, 7, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9, 9, 8,7};        

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
       System.out.println("sum of spots 3-16  =  " + 
       ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,3,16));
       System.out.println("sum of spots 2-9  =  " + 
       ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,2,9));
       System.out.println("# of 4s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,4));
       System.out.println("# of 9s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,9));
       System.out.println("# of 7s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one,7)); 
       one = ArrayFunHouse.removeVal(one, 7);
       System.out.println("new array with all 7s removed  =  " + 
       Arrays.toString(one));
       System.out.println("# of 7s  =  " + ArrayFunHouse.getCount(one, 7));
    }
}
```

My output

```
 [7, 4, 10, 0, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 9, 7]
sum of spots 3-6  =  14
sum of spots 2-9  =  34
 # of 4s  =  1
# of 9s  =  1
# of 7s  =  3
new array with all 7s removed  =  [4, 10, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 9]
# of 7s  =  0

[4, 10, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 9]
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at ArrayFunHouse.getSum(ArrayFunHouse.java:22)
 at ArrayFunHouseRunner.main(ArrayFunHouseRunner.java:30)
```

I need help on this. The first one works fine but the second one comes an error.

Comment: The wording of the questions seems to indicate this as some sort of a homework assignment, Stack Overflow is not a place for homework help, that is the job of your teachers.

Comment: Copy/paste error: `getSum(one,3,16)` should be `getSum(two,3,16)`. You forgot to change the first parameter.

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta [you're wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3079302). Although I agree that this question could be reduced to a more concise [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @iled, what exactly am I wrong about, I didn't understand what statement I made that was wrong?

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta Here: *Stack Overflow is not a place for homework help*. I provided a link for a discussion on meta that clarifies that.

Comment: Although according to the meta it says: Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help; your professor is likely to be a better resource at this stage than Stack Overflow.

Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster. Do not use a “homework” tag, but mention it in the question text if relevant, but he didn't do the latter, so my comment still holds.

Comment: However, I admit through the comments I have read from higher rep users on the site, I thought that Stack Overflow is not a place for homework help, thanks for the clarification, @iled

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code: `ArrayFunHouse.getSum(one,3,16));`, you pass in the stop index as 16 to the **first array**, what you need to do is pass it to the second array **two**. This is due to the fact that the length of the first array is less than 16. In addition, in some other lines of code, you have passed in one, instead of passing in two. Try it to see if it works.

Comment: @Abdullah, do you mind selecting it as a right answer, so in the future, people know that the question is answered and can reference it better if needed, thanks.